Lattice points inside $x^2+y^2=r^2$
In the interior of the square of side length $N$, whose two corners are lattice points $(m,m)\in\Bbb Z^2$, there are $(N-1)^2$ lattice points.
So, in the intetior of the circle $$x^2+y^2=r^2,\,\, r\in\Bbb R,$$
there must be at least $$\lfloor(\sqrt{\pi}r-1)^2\rfloor$$ lattice points.
Is this true? What is the best lower bound?
Edit: I found this related post.

Here is the relevant Wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem. The best known-bound on the difference between the number of lattice points and $\pi r^{2}$ is $O(r^{0.63})$.

It reminds me of this famous video. It doesn't really adress your question though. https://youtube.com/watch?v=NaL_Cb42WyY

Well, the interior of the square of side length $N=5$ with vertices at $(0,0)$, $(4,3)$ [and two more] has $24$ interior points rather than $(N-1)^2=16$.

Couldn't this be done by Pick's Theorem?
